# Enter inputs taken by a bash script automatically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need to pass two inputs to my bash script `enter_name.sh`. The first one is `Y` or `N`. The next one is the name of the user.

I tried `echo "Harry\nY\n" | bash enter_name.sh` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you considered trying the `echo` command by itself to see if it outputs the data that the script expects to read?

Comment: You seem to be providing inputs in the opposite order of what you described. Also, different versions of `echo` are hopelessly inconsistent in how they treat `\n` (and some other things); I'd use `printf` instead (`printf '%s\n' "Y" "Harry"`).

Comment: @loadbox : Did you ensure that `enter_name.sh` reads its inputs from stdin?

Comment: @GordonDavisson printf worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To check if the first argument is y/n, and second argument is not empty:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ "$1" = [yYnY] ]] || { echo "First argument must be y/n"; exit 1; }
[ -z "$2" ] && { echo "Second argument must be a user name"; exit 1; }
echo $1 $2
```

Example:

```
$ ./enter_name.sh 
First argument must be y/n
$ ./enter_name.sh a x
First argument must be y/n
$ ./enter_name.sh N
Second argument must be user name
$ ./enter_name.sh N some_user
N some_user
```